# Zxing Issue: cannot get MatrixToImageConfig working with javascript

Tags: javascript, report, barcode, zxing, birt

I'm trying to implement Zxing 3.3.3 barcode generation in BIRT 4.8 using javascript on an image. But when it gets to using the MatrixToImageConfig class I keep getting the error

> "MatrixToImageConfig" is not function, it is object.

I got the error initially without the "new" keyword. I added it in and I still get the same issue.

```
var biConfig = new Packages.com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageConfig(fgnd, bgnd);
```

Anyone come across this or know more about using Java libraries in javascript that can show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Needed an extra library jar to import the com.google.zxing.client.j2se package

> javase-3.1.1